# Why is my animation showing just on first execution?

Tags: android, animation, frame, show

My app starts with an opening (welcome) activity that shows a brief frame animation. I'm using [this class](https://github.com/tigerjj/FasterAnimationsContainer) to do so.
The first time I run the app everything works just fine. But if I finish it, the next times the animation doesn't show at all. The only way I can see it again is by forcing termination first (from Android app manager).

This is how I'm starting the animation:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_opening);

    ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.openingAnimImg);
    frameAnimation = FasterAnimationsContainer.getInstance(img);
    prepareFrames();
    frameAnimation.setOnAnimationStoppedListener(this);
    frameAnimation.start();
}
```

Once the animation finishes, I start another activity.
To close the app, I'm just using the back key until there are no more activities on the stack. It may be important to mention that this opening activity has `noHistory="true"`, so it's not reachable once the second activity starts.

I tracked the problem and I found a strange behaviour on this function:

```
private class FramesSequenceAnimation implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ImageView imageView = mSoftReferenceImageView.get();
        if (!mShouldRun || imageView == null) {
            mIsRunning = false;
            if (mOnAnimationStoppedListener != null) {
                mOnAnimationStoppedListener.onAnimationStopped();
            }
            return;
        }
        mIsRunning = true;

        /* isShown() is returning false here! */
        if (imageView.isShown()) {
            AnimationFrame frame = getNext();
            GetImageDrawableTask task = new GetImageDrawableTask(imageView);
            try {
                task.execute(frame.getResourceId());
            }catch(RejectedExecutionException ree){
                Log.e("ANIMATION", "Rejected execution");
            }
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, frame.getDuration());
        }
    }
}
```

So the ImageView is not showing the animation because that commented line is returning false. Why is this happening? And why does the program work the first time? What's changing between the first and second execution?

If you need more information or I wasn't clear, just let me know.

Comment: You cannot access `Views` from another thread. What for you implement `Runnable`? Sure it will return `false` to your `ImageView`.

Comment: Then why does it work the first time? `isShown` returns `true` the first time I execute the app and everything goes well. Any ideas?

Comment: take a look on your `onCreate()` method. You start animation there - from the main (UI) thread. Use debug mode and set breakpoints to notice which lines work and where are problems. Also you will be able to inspect your variables.

Comment: I did that to check what does `isShown(img)` return on `onCreate()` method. Is returning `false` always, even on the first run. So two questions here: Why? And also, why does it return `true` on the other thread?

Comment: this is hard for me to understand behavior and the way `ImageView` goes through, cuz not whole code is shown. But in my opinion this is a little complicated, try to simplify it and 100% you should reorganize your inner class without new thread, it is totally incorrect. Also I found that `isShown()` method's behavior is close to `isVisible()`. when I had deal with animation I had similar issue. Try to create global `boolean` variable instead and set `true` when it started or `false` when it stopped. For now I cannot help 100% with this code.